# MS Excel Compare Columns And Add Additional Info To Beside Original Column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

really need some professional ms excel guru,
I'm working in small company HR and we have a list of names of our clients and employees (3000 names give or take) with their salary by the side,

now our management wants to add like say "bonuses" to the salary but don't want to add it directly to it's cell but a column next to the "salary's" column,

I've drawn a chart of basically what I'm talking about,
I know it's doable or any way of comparing a list of our employee's name and adding additional columns to the employee's row?

[image: Image Of Basically What I'm Talking About]

Comment: You can do it with [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) function.

Comment: While dealing with employee names in Excel you may like to create a unique employee ID assigned to each name. With employee ID in place, tracking and lookup gets a lot easier as there’s no issue of duplicate names. With employee ID you can very easily use simple functions like INDEX MATCH or VLOOKUP to do the intended task without worrying about duplicates. You may like to create a master list of employees and employee IDs going forward as a standard practice in your company, and a lot of Excel searches & data analysis for several reasons shall be very easy.

Comment: Thanks Mate, Researched into the so called "named range" attribute, i have found the solution! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Use the following formula in column C in the New Sheet, Column A is Name, Column B the salary, Column C for Bonus, in C2 write:
`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Added!$A$2:$B$11,2,FALSE),"")`
A2 is the first name of your employee
A2:B11 the Data change it to correspond to all employees and their bonus
$ for absolute reference, you can drag the formula and the references are fix
2 to return the bonus column
False for exact value of the Name
Added is the sheet name where you have the bonus change it to your sheet
IFerror to return empty "" in case if the name is not found (maybe some employee without bonus)